# XML Deserialize how to traverse to 3rd child

Tags: c#, xml

I have this web service that retun this xml file

```
<QCalls ts="Wed Jan 30 03:05:16 2019 UTC" cts="Wed Jan 30 03:04:04 2019 UTC" tzo="-28800" al="false">
 <Q id="815" n="Lo" wt="506098" ch="5" cwt="470" ct="3" co="4" ca="0" cw="9" awt="119366" act="84" cbh="2" ofi="0" ofo="0" catqos="0" dlro="336">
  <phone id="815" n="Lo"" wt="0" ch="1" cwt="1" ct="1" co="1" ca="0" cw="0" awt="0" act="417" cbh="2" ofi="0" ofo="0" catqos="0"/>
 </Q>
 <Q id="819" n="Hi" wt="70780" ch="2" cwt="156" ct="1" co="1" ca="0" cw="3" awt="51904" act="91" cbh="2" ofo="0" catqos="0" dlro="41">
  <phone id="819" n="Hi" wt="0" ch="1" cwt="1" ct="1" co="1" ca="0" cw="0" awt="0" act="181" cbh="2" ofo="0" catqos="0"/>
 </Q>
</QCalls>
```

I am using xmldeserializer to retrieve data from it. I need the `phone` tag data which reside on the 3rd level of the xml file. But the problem is when I retrieve it. It only gets the first `phone` data I can't get the second data which relies on the second Q. I have these code on c# to retrieve the data

```
[XmlRoot("MultipleFilters")]
public class MultipleFilters
{
   [XmlElement("QCalls")]
   public QCalls QCalls { get; set; }
}

public class QCalls
{
    [XmlAnyElement("Q")]
    public Phone phone { get; set; }
}
public class Phone
{
    [XmlElement("phone")]
    public List<QItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class QItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("n")]
    public string queue { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("cw")]
    public int cw { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("cwt")]
    public int cwt { get; set; }
}

calls = (MultipleFilters)serializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());
```

How Can I get all the data within the XML File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XmlArray take two levels of xml tags and put into 1 class.  You have a class for each xml element so you do not need two use the attribute array. Your classes were wrong so I fixed them.  I also used a file for testing instead of your stream.  The code below was tested and works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QCalls));

            QCalls qCalls = (QCalls)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("QCalls")]
    public class QCalls
    {
        [XmlElement("Q")]
        public List<Q> q { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Q")]
    public class Q
    {
        [XmlElement("phone")]
        public Phone phone { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("phone")]
    public class Phone
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("n")]
        public string queue { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("cw")]
        public int cw { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("cwt")]
        public int cwt { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class structure doesn't fully conform with the XML, it should be something like this:

```
class Phone {...}
class Q {
...
  [XmlElement("phone")]
  Phone Phone {get;set;}
...
}
class QCalls{
...
  [XmlElement("Q")]
  List<Q> QItems {get;set;}
...
}
```